# How to build a type from enum values in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

Given the following:

```
enum FooKeys {
  FOO = 'foo',
  BAR = 'bar',
}
```

I'd like to make an interface like this one, but instead of defining keys by hand, build it out of enum's values.

```
interface Foo {
  foo: string
  bar: string
}
```

Is something like this possible with TypeScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Yes, you can use enum values as keys.  And you can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) like the standard library's [`Record<K, V>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.3.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1449-L1454) to prevent repetition:

```
enum FooKeys {
  FOO = 'foo',
  BAR = 'bar',
}

// probably all you need, but it's a type alias
type FooType = Record<FooKeys, string>;

// if you need an interface instead you can do this
interface FooInterface extends FooType {};
```

And you can verify that it works:

```
declare const foo: FooInterface;
foo.foo; // okay
foo[FooKeys.FOO]; // okay

foo.bar; // okay
foo[FooKeys.BAR]; // okay

foo.baz; // error
```

Does that work for you?  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: What is `Record` in `Record<FooKeys, string>`? Why did you decide to add yet another arbitrary type in your app/code/module? Why do you need extra type?

Comment: It's a [utility type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt), the definition of which in the standard library is linked in the answer above.

Answer (score 78):

> How to build a type from enum values in TypeScript?

An enum can hold string and number values.

**For strings:**
you can create a string union from enum values using a template string

```js
enum FooKeys {
  FOO = 'foo',
  BAR = 'bar',
}

type FooValues =`${FooKeys}`; // this equals 'foo' | 'bar'
```

**For numbers:** we can either create string union the same way or:
[starting TS 5.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0-beta/#all-enums-are-union-enums)

> TypeScript 5.0 manages to make all enums into union enums by creating
> a unique type for each computed member. That means that all enums can
> now be narrowed and have their members referenced as types as well.

Which means:

```js
enum MagicNumbers {
a = 1,
b = 42
}

const numberA : MagicNumbers = 1;
const numberB : MagicNumbers = 2; // will raise an error since TS 5.0
```

[Experiment by yourself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.0-dev.20230313#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nA0sAngZygbwFBVgeXygF4oByAMwTIBpcoAhAQQCUTyAjAQwCdbsAvtmwBjOCDQAXKKEgA1LgBswwfAGsuKAFywEydO3hJUaAHQxCUAPRWZPHnB6jxUmeAgLlwGFwCWinSN9DFIAIio4UOExCWkpHl8QAHMAVRBfcXVNHQADABJMIJMBHPZwhCiY13jE1PTxH39cgqL0ErKjBl5Q61tge0dhWWgAWS4k3xEAOUgOfowcLnYARjoOdgAWACZBaJdpdzmeJigdMYnp2fmVgG5nWKhD-oZTqHPJmYgjkKgtgAYtgBmG69OwOHg0R5waTLKCOKDbbBAA)

**For both:**
Combining the above, we can build an `EnumAsUnion` type helper as follows

enum-as-union.ts

```js
type StringValues<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? T[K] : never;
}[keyof T];

type NumberValues<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? T[K] : never;
}[keyof T];

/**
 * Usage : type EnumValues = EnumAsUnion<typeof anEnum>
 */
type EnumAsUnion<T> = `${StringValues<T>}` | NumberValues<T>;
```

Example:

```js
import { EnumAsUnion } from 'enum-as-union';

enum anEnum {
  val1 = 'a',
  val2 = 'b',
  val3 = 1,
  val4 = 2,
}

type EnumValues = EnumAsUnion<typeof anEnum>;

let t: EnumValues;
t = 'a';
t = 'b';
t = 'c'; // error, as expected

t = 1;
t = 2;
t = 3; // error, as expected
```

[Try it here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.0-dev.20230313#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwGoEMA2BXCAzgDwAqAfFALxQDeAUFFANoDSUKUA1hCAPYBmUEgF0AXENbCoEAB7AIyACYEoBBClRQA-BJZTxyCADcI8ANx0Avk259BIi3VCQoAOVwBbAEamseQqQU1PSMrOzIXDwCQmK6UrLySirInj7w2nFQBsamFta20Q50dAD0AFRlDGVQAKoEmKjQ4s7QAKIpHn74KtTtngCCBDXIiLzIRC3RmMh9HmRVJU7gbR2Dw6Pj5FRQAAYAJDRwSGhdAeSWO1AAPm6pvjjdgY50Cp5Q07O0DFBGOACM2wA5JhAQAab6-bAAJiBXjBEJwAGZtn9wYxIQAWbZQ8GWYotKCzU49QmrIYjMYTZZTGYdMiObAQYBQYDiIkPQgWZnUYGArmwvlOIEAYz5UBKJWk8HgvHgoPeKlkkGF8kU+JR-OoUM1UERZnFktMMrlCukMmVqroQA)

Comment: really nice and clean, thanks

Answer (score 9):

> [@hackape 's solution][1] is great, but I found minimal duplication
> extending his solution as below:
>
> ```
> type ReverseMap<T extends Record<keyof T, any>> = {
>   [V in T[keyof T]]: {
>     [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never;
>   }[keyof T];
> }
>
> const Map = {
>   'FOO': "foo" as "foo",
>   'BAR': "bar" as "bar",
> }
>
> const reverseMap: ReverseMap<typeof Map> = Object.entries(Map).reduce((rMap, [k, v]) => {
>   rMap[v] = k;
>   return rMap;
> }, {} as any);
>
> export type Values = keyof typeof reverseMap; // 'foo' | 'bar';
> ```
>
> ReverseMap implementation is well explained [here][2]
>
> [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60768453/5519365   [2]:
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/55209457/5519365

Update:
I found a much simpler solution for ReverseMap

```
const Obj = {
 FOO: 'foo',
 BAR: 'bar',
} as const;

type ReverseMap<T> = T[keyof T];

export type Values = ReverseMap<typeof Obj>; // 'foo' | 'bar';
```

Answer (score 6):

Does this answer your question?

```js
enum FOO_BAR {
    F = "foo",
    B = "bar",
}

type FooType = Record<FOO_BAR, string>;

const obj: FooType = {
    // you can use enum values, better for refactoring
    [FOO_BAR.F]: "action foo",
    [FOO_BAR.B]: "action bar",

    // or use enum values
    // foo: "action foo",
    // bar: "action bar",
};

obj[FOO_BAR.F]; // -> "action foo"
obj["foo"];     // -> "action foo"

// If you want partial keys
type FooTypePartial = Partial<FooType>;

const objPartial: FooTypePartial = {
    [FOO_BAR.F]: "action foo",
};

objPartial["foo"]; // -> "action foo", may be undefined
```