# Combine two types into an interface elegantly in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

### My goal

I have a string `enum E` and an `interface I` with identical sets of keys. I want to construct a new mapped type. For each shared key `k`, it should use the enum value `E.k` as a property name. The type of member `I.k` should be this new property's type.

#### Some background / motivation for my use case

I get objects from a REST API. I cannot change their structure. The objects' key names are **very** unreadable and ugly because of legacy reasons (I simulate this in `FooNames` in the example). 
This makes development painful and unnecessarily increases errors both in code, but more critically in understanding, when working with these objects and manipulating them.

We have hidden these names using a clean interface of our own (simulated by via `"first" | "second" | "third"`). However, when writing back objects to the backend, they need to have the "ugly" structure again.
There are several dozen object types (with different sets of fields each), which is what makes it so painful to work with confusing field names.

We are attempting to minimize redundancy - while still having static type and structure checking via TS compiler. Thus, a mapped type that triggers typechecks based on the existing abstractions would be very helpful.

#### Code example

**Can the `BackendObject` type below be somehow realized as a mapped type in Typescript?** I have thus far failed to find a way. See [this playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAEEUFcFMGcBcCWB7AdgKBKAKgd2aLIgLYAOANtKAIYBGCATtQMZJqyinQOjK0BW0VqHgBPLgBpQ0AHQBzGaABmyHtRHiqAMWTIZ+memipIxUDuQA5asTigA3ulDLEDBKAC8oAORaAkgBKAMrYAPr+AKIAMgAi3hJOhEJoACaePthhkbGhQREAwgDylnEJzvAAFq5pXt6V1aFKiNDkKaEAzO3e6AC+6Iio8NxKLNq62Jocjs5NbvAAXITwDANyZUnMqYsmxLTc6-UMKYu0upTUGH1YBjTk5Mi4yqqgcsbciMyguC3kALQqDFsaT4glYHFwiEqSwYkFYkAYVAuaTEXGYFSEAGtYPN+oNhqNzAw0ENUClCgIhPAADxaZqtay2DjQAAeJJSHAx0FEyCU5jpKQmXFgUlpLQFkwAfA5Ek0xdiHABtADSoAGfLFDLgAF1FqLWoK4MqtX0+pgwBFmTYKFQQZTVagROjQMxqLAbbzkPDVcRqHIBtQGKINFxQAAiCyhnGUeDO9HMTkpCzk0ELQnE4xkimsKmc7m8lHQHnmXSa4UWA2wKVeeygEAAQlAAFU3dIdqBc8LQKhkDGAG7UcgwWAy-nymugRIzVwIRbeeLOWtgAtozFM3vcUS4dEIuuTjZbUAAVnW5SqR0WI3IboSWGkrKYAAUiaRZ-UOIgOAPYAQV-HoGkkVAFIPwHe5vhSbpnBNdAzVAB8AkKAAhKIIgAWUWbAnRUO4HlWaFYXgeEqA-UAEQAR0gVx-xEAhcBWIZeCzeAOFoFgMXteACBSah4DoV1oFxIYGBGZgxmQRC2IzZM7RrEc5UWaYF38YIsj8aIYkWRhVhPHBVPU3ICmKGJQkybZTD2BgdMONpZVaDp2hOM5oAuPdrn0VywAAQRSYDUDkLtoEeWz2VAH0TFAoMSOYczuG-WwaFJaQGCJBhflIIlUGgABuDznXoj4B22AgEB4j58LhBFeB4AtY1XGh+0Qcg6EoRJoKwPwYgiTyolAABxQpusWAJnPIRAAC8qDfGgOFeTKVk+H1SC4ZFNFASAiD8x1EXoZYWDYVBP1OddQFGzko2gGMkyYnQGAkv9SUWO7OVJaTswsUsJHLSV0kUrBaEo1otrWuRyCDW1WCkf6Y1gSAltUIY0loIMasAxgCKI2r42HHoctgzylqJFgKlAABGRYIjbABqUA-DxYTRhggYhJEqgnqkpiSZpflSzvNkOC0vyRX5CspUU4Kxz3BUtHtdV6RsbVdWFyYpa1LLF1l8UhWdC5uxjPZ7RSFlqKR8wpC3D5iZI7tHkqKhIBBoNgq7eXJeltU9RSUsdQ1ispe5+XYBkLRVfVoJREGahmSA5A4FQOovlUDE1e7UjoHXNwqEW0g8LVAW5F+ftB2o4xTFa3pYK0Ty-CiRsAgiGm8VJaj1t9aAcRqq6UxutnSRJ9Ie8zFNOfegPPvGSVcZgrB8fS5AidAAAmRYlS5FwxWDOwIShe3QehVZOyhpZGvIUB-satJUA+KglAytlwfgQT8VE4tkArBfpWcKWSwDmRZgQb287rC-lYH+bpNikm9jsCyQCR6MhkNZb2pxkDnFQAkU0WAgiNnyPkCIQQgh9TePNU+klEr3w3o-emz8B6vXgAvLmGoA68wzByLkRYPYViFmKEWH816tAlguUACp2Lu39oyb27DlYYi1GXK4YAbgAl4F6FkVpKAbxfu3VaFgB79xIYPSkdDYFwBFOPIUC8JToGjIQZAtgtG6JobqXQ2jqxyT4QpV2384F-3gN7bwcULpVD8vEdxIC4FgNSN7Y8wTSzwLPCkb2ywYAyKnmAAAEoUAA6hEAAahEAIBhFAELmmVG+6ZSFMXMFXGudcKEszTI3PRrA6GWCvh7HmLI+Z70FhrNprJmHtlYbyCRQpOH6m+mLUcbiBFCJls00SrSA7iKVkKP2DC4FSOcO1VAhdEBpFgOHXizJk60WoMjAgLBRKwCZG2QCKcfTwDRHhIsGIkl4wJnPNEoAHKgHyNY2gAxtqMD2igA600RCw0oJ2daeE84nUhNwAcG9hxYA9s7RkCUVpazVGgYidMWY4iZk-MS2BwV2HGXMRYCpfCBBCOENSsR5x52kc4MJD1BHeEyLS-SeQiglHnFA7gTLHTVApXUWJjR+T2XnEglB0j0FgErtXWuEQakEmoUxdoVIDTEutJWHh4tJkLiwLIBQDgXDks6f5PoUzhEOi1SS2ACoSZalAAA5YqwAA+-KGDuulc5B06tabbN2fsyOTweADENsyVYLzp5vPngAFkWEEaApAAw8RxZxMM4tQyMRTJwbg5Dp47SYKwYFHAFFO1QIwwCBYOCbF2P8tITMzmEFWKo++Krn4e1gDQvVEyeGf0vqJTUmk3V+W9opARKRaAjotTpZws9OIFlHSsPyPqnIXE9TFBge4rWgGgpYiw3bFZyl7c4qc8kB1mpnFe5w07Z1UpUpy+l87OBEiXZoWc3gBHOF3TpFlxxb1ARnfLWcHLsjGW5UZIJP6309h7J+0AAAGP9e5rIGqnSB2wr4xXBS6K+xdCGuCLASdAHSe7oIV0qbqW+GZc12hqobJol99oTgJZQ7QtGXrqvoXw3t7S+l51Fi49kGHBE2v6XmDWPamKLNPUxIRWoFSEYLCHdW+QdY9hoMwC5HBMoIGojVIs3gVOaEgvu8uyLqOgAHmQxj0BmOQmBZ21mdiePdv4700k-Mx1yGExe1xV7plqlzEWb2GywCWGKr52FQkEU1QUaBUAhchy8F5N4e98tzPQSAA) for all the code in this question.

```js
// Two simple abstractions per object type, e.g. for a type Foo....
enum FooNames {
  first = 'FIRST_FIELD',
  second = 'TT_FIELD_SECOND',
  third = 'third_field_33'
}
interface FooTypes {
  first: string,
  second: number,
  third: boolean
}
// ... allow for generic well-formed objects with structure and typechecks:
interface FrontendObject<FieldNames extends keyof FieldTypes, FieldTypes> {
  fields: {[K in FieldNames]: FieldTypes[K]}
}

// Example object in the case of our imaginary type "Foo":
let checkedFooObject: FrontendObject<keyof typeof FooNames,FooTypes> = {
  fields: {  
    first: '',   // typechecks everywhere!
    second: 5,
    third: false,
//  extraProp: 'this is also checked and disallowed'
  }
}

// PROBLEM: The following structure is required to write objects back into database
interface FooBackendObject { 
  fields: {
    FIRST_FIELD: string,
    TT_FIELD_SECOND_TT: number,
    third_field_33: boolean
    // ...
    // Adding new fields manually is cumbersome and error-prone;
    // critical: no static structure or type checks available
  }
}
// IDEAL GOAL: Realize this as generic mapped type using the abstractions above like:
let FooObjectForBackend: BackendObject<FooNames,FooTypes> = {
  // build the ugly object, but supported by type and structure checks
};
```

### My attempts thus far

#### 1. Enum (Names) + Interface (types)

```js
interface BackendObject1<FieldNames extends string, FieldTypes> {
  fields: {
    // FieldTypes cannot be indexed by F, which is now the ugly field name
    [F in FieldNames]: FieldTypes[F]; 
    // Syntax doesn't work; no reverse mapping in string-valued enum
    [F in FieldNames]: FieldTypes[FieldNames.F]; 
  }
}
// FAILURE Intended usage:
type FooObjectForBackend1 = BackendObject1<FooNames,FooTypes>;
```

#### 2. Use ugly keys for field type abstraction instead

```js
interface FooTypes2 {
  [FooNames.first]: string,
  [FooNames.second]: number,
  [FooNames.third]: boolean,
}

// SUCCESS Generic backend object type
interface BackendObject2<FieldNames extends keyof FieldTypes, FieldTypes> {
  fields: {
    [k in FieldNames]: FieldTypes[k]
  }
}
// ... for our example type Foo:
type FooBackend = BackendObject2<FooNames, FooTypes2>
let someFooBackendObject: FooBackend = {
  fields: {
    [FooNames.first]: 'something',
    [FooNames.second]: 5,
    [FooNames.third]: true
  }
}

// HOWEVER....  Generic frontend object FAILURE
interface FrontendObject2<NiceFieldNames extends string, FieldNames extends keyof FieldTypes, FieldTypes> {
  fields: {
    // Invalid syntax; no way to access enum and no matching of k
    [k in NiceFieldNames]: FieldTypes[FieldNames.k]
  }
}
```

#### 3. Combine object abstraction as tuples, using string literal types

```js
// Field names and types in one interface:
interface FooTuples {
  first: ['FIRST_FIELD', string]
  second: ['TT_FIELD_SECOND', number]
  third: ['third_field_33', boolean]
}


// FAILURE
interface BackendObject3<TypeTuples> {
  fields: {
    // e.g. { first: string }
    // Invalid syntax for indexing
    [k in TypeTuples[1] ]: string|number|boolean
  }
}
```

#### 4. One "fields" object per type

```js
// Abstractions for field names and types combined into a single object
interface FieldsObject {
  fields: {
    [niceName: string]: {
      dbName: string,
      prototype: string|boolean|number // used only for indicating type
    }
  }
}
let FooFields: FieldsObject = {
  fields: {
    first: {
      dbName: 'FIRST_FIELD',
      prototype: ''      
    },
    second: {
      dbName: 'TT_FIELD_SECOND',
      prototype: 0
    },
    third: {
      dbName: 'third_field3',
      prototype: true,
    }
  }
}

// FAIL: Frontend object type definition 
interface FrontendObject3<FieldsObject extends string> {
  fields: {
    // Cannot access nested type of 'prototype'
    [k in keyof FieldsObject]: FieldsObject[k][prototype];  
  }
}
// FAIL: Backendobject type definition
interface BackendObject3<FieldsObject extends string> {
  fields: {
    [k in keyof ...]:  // No string literal type for all values of 'dbName'
  }
}
```

Comment: What benefit are type safe backend objects giving you? I mean, if frontend code always uses the nice frontend types, the only place you benefit from type safe backend types is in mapping code - which I would expect to be a generic function making use of the mapping metadata. It seems just as easy to ensure correctness of the mapping metadata as it does to ensure correctness of the backend object type definition?

Comment: @meriton You are precisely right; this all started as an attempt to make the mapping code type-safe.
I also attempted to find a way to describe a generic mapping function which used the metadata, but got stuck much sooner / had less inspiration on how to do it....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the following should work for you:

```
type BackendObject<
  E extends Record<keyof E, keyof any>,
  I extends Record<keyof E, any>
  > = {
    fields: {
      [P in E[keyof E]]: I[{
        [Q in keyof E]: E[Q] extends P ? Q : never
      }[keyof E]]
    }
  }

interface FooBackendObject extends
  BackendObject<typeof FooNames, FooTypes> { }
```

The type `BackendObject<E, I>` is not an interface, but you can declare an interface for any particular concrete values of `E` and `I` as in `FooBackendObject` above.  So, in `BackendObject<E, I>`, we expect `E` to be the mapping to keys (represented in `FooBackendObject` by the `FooNames` *value*, whose type is `typeof FooNames`... you *can't* just use the `FooNames` *type* here, since that [doesn't contain the mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396312/2887218).), and `I` to be the mapping to values (represented in the `FooBackendObject` by the interface `FooTypes`).

The mapped/conditional types being used might be a bit ugly, but this is what we're doing: first, the keys of the `fields` object come from the *values* of `E` (`E[keyof E]`).  For each key `P` in that, we find the key of `E` which corresponds to it (`{[Q in keyof E]: E[Q] extends P ? Q : never}[keyof E]`), and then use that key to index into `I` for the value type.

Let's explain `{[Q in keyof E]: E[Q] extends P ? Q : never}[keyof E]` more fully.  Generally a type like `{[Q in keyof E]: SomeType<Q>}[keyof E]` will be the union of `SomeType<Q>` for all `Q` in `keyof E`.  You can cash it out with a concrete type if that makes more sense... if `E` is `{a: string, b: number}`, then `{[Q in keyof E]: SomeType<Q>}` will be `{a: SomeType<'a'>, b: SomeType<'b'>}`, and then we [look up](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) its values at keys `keyof E`, which is `{a: SomeType<'a'>, b: SomeType<'b'>}['a'|'b']`, which becomes `SomeType<'a'> | SomeType<'b'>`.  In our case, `SomeType<Q>` is `E[Q] extends P ? Q : never`, which evaluates to `Q` if `E[Q]` matches `P`, and `never` otherwise.  Thus we are getting the union of `Q` values in `keyof E` for which `E[Q]` matches `P`.  There should be just one of those (if the enum doesn't have two keys with the same value).

It might be useful for you to go through the exercise of manually evaluating `BackendObject<typeof FooNames, FooTypes>` to see it happen.

You can verify that it behaves as desired.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Freaking beautiful. And awesomely explained. The link was also a very educational read. Thanks a lot. I'm digesting and playing around, will accept answer as soon as I've got it working :)

Comment: The fact that a `enum` _type_ doesn't contain the mapping, but is instead just the union of the literal _values_ was a huge breakthrough for my understanding. Thanks again!

Comment: I've understood the general idea pretty well I think. However, I'm hung up on a bit of syntax, particularly the `[keyof E]` at the end. More generally, while I understand our _semantic_ goal (you explained it very well), I have trouble understanding the general syntax `T[{ <mapped type> }[keyof U]]`. Would you mind going into that a tiny bit more?

Comment: Okay, I've added to the answer (with "Let's explain...").  Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Once again, I thank you dearly. 
Not only is it very kind of you to follow-up, but you're also an incredibly gifted teacher/explainer. I've learned quite a lot. _bows deeply_
I had been manually evaluating the type, and so it clicked instantly after reading your latest addition. It was just the syntax which I was still unsure about. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link as well, it seems reading TypeScript Deep Dive + Typescript Handbook has still left me with some knowledge gaps.... I'll remember to dig around there when I have the time.

A last question: Would it be correct to say that we're actually not looking up the _values_, but looking up the _types_ at the keys `keyof E` in your in-depth example?

Comment: Yes, we're looking up the types of the property values (as opposed to the property keys).