# Advanced typing for object remapper

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function that lets a caller remap an object given a specific mapping. The resulting object should be able to know the new new field names and types.

Is this possible in typescript? I think all I need at this point is a return type. This is non-working code I have:

```
const mapping = {
    a: "learn",
    b: "state"
}

const original = {
    a: false,
    b: 0
}

const map = <
    Mapping,
    Original
>(
    mapping: Mapping,
    states: Original
): {
    [key: Mapping[key]]: Original[key] //WHAT IS THE CORRECT TYPE HERE?
} => {
    return Object.keys(original).reduce((total, key) => {
        return {
            ...total,
            [mapping[key]]: original[key] //THERE IS AN ERROR HERE TOO BUT I AM NOT WORRIED ABOUT THAT RIGHT NOW
        }
    }, {})
}

const remapped = map(mapping, original)

console.log(remapped)
console.log(remapped.learn)
console.log(remapped.state)
```

I am essentially trying to rename `a` to `learn` and `b` to `state`. The code is working functionally but I am getting a type error ('key' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need @jcalz's amazing [`UnionToIntersection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286) utility type in your toolbox.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never;
```

Now let's make our own utility type:

```
1    type Remap<A extends { [k: string]: string }, B> =
2        keyof B extends keyof A ?
3        { [P in keyof B & keyof A]: { [k in A[P]]: B[P] } } extends
4        { [s: string]: infer V } ? 
5        UnionToIntersection<V>
6        : never
7        : never;
```

Explain:

- ln:1, constrain A's value to be string.
- ln:2, constrain that all B's keys present in A
- ln:3, map to `{ "a": {"learn": boolean}, "b": {"state": number} }`
- ln:4, take the value part, which becomes: `{"learn": boolean} | {"state": number}` union
- ln:5, apply the `UnionToIntersection` magic!

Put things together:

```
const mapping = {
    a: "learn",
    b: "state",
} as const;   // mark as `const` is necessary to infer value as string literal
              // else it'll just be string
const original = {
    a: false,
    b: 0,
};

const map = <
    M extends { [k: string]: string },
    O extends { [k: string]: any }
>(mapping: M, original: O): Remap<M, O> => {
    return Object.keys(original).reduce((total, key) => {
        return {
            ...total,
            [mapping[key]]: original[key]
        }
    }, {} as any); // as any to mute error
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=32&ssc=3&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4AoKJqAChiggA8c4ATfKAEM4IKAH5WAawBcsAJR0aANyQJeUWXAhK8Crj36sWMqAjgAzPFAwLay1bwUSMGqFp24A3PXqhIUACUIAFtBMHIAQQ5uCD4BAG8oAG0TfGBcMwBzAF1ZNIy4TKgAXwAaKAAhGgZmKEkIECRzSuiDAXrG5qixRmZEpIAFUzg6hqaWgDJRzqgI3Kh+yWHZwez5itWSrf1Y-l6mfvw89Kz5s0tcKAA1LZ7a+DJ0LBwCYlIUciuqfdd3PB-NNo8N56EQUGkoKEwGAsnQFj9BLIAEQAGwgglwcCRpR+ACNkWlBDhsfRikIBGC4GkQZSIUgMpkzIIUXD4gjZOZmYQcbV8VAAAw44o08HASFhOHkH4AWVauwSyVSJ0K83ysLKPwA8nK4gtFccCjlZMJRMV6FQWFCYYVZNLyvSEIy4MzZJq5LIglDyHaoJrqjQ2bVcBBgABXTG+3EAKzeADoOvgWA6ncy5LHg7xQ0QICwWMAkMBmeUOrYAz8gyHwyNA7Va0xYw384WUTy67WklasikGmtZMmmSjuyBsuXmGbamUFmTBAITXJvMKgA)

---

I came across another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208690/combine-two-types-into-an-interface-elegantly-in-typescript) by jcalz, which provides a more elegant solution than mine. Check that answer for explanation. I'll append it here:

```
type Remap2<
    M extends { [k: string]: string },
    O extends { [P in keyof M]: any }
> = {
    [P in M[keyof M]]: O[
        { [K in keyof M]: M[K] extends P ? K : never }[keyof M]
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this version:

```
type Remap<
M extends { [k: string]: string },
O extends { [k: string]: any }
> = {
    [P in keyof M  as M[P]]: P extends keyof O ? O[P] : never
} & Omit<O, keyof M>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShC2BDMAeAUFTUCyUIA9gIA7AEwGcoBvKAbQGsAuKc4AJwEtiBzAXWdaceUAL4AaDFgDyeQiQrU6TFuy59miYiFFoAfFAC81SZloAFKFyj0IIAPYAzHJkSVs53vygWCRMpRt7JxkAfigpDyhmYggANwg2NBEoADJw%20A5gFCkxa1tHHF00NABjO2JWKCQwMDVDYywoRGYAIgAbCEQ2YhaJRoAjVtZEIl6kpsoyiuAAbmKpyrtObi5ENvqqEybmBzXyCD6sQagABgkROdLyyur69EbcX3lKGgYBVR4vQTrxLZkn-yKN4qITqJpaHS6AAU1VqPGY2FySw4K2Ia2YUgAlMw4NUUIjwvoDPpNo02BBgABXbrhfoAKwgJWAADpAuQocjUWtMczyaRKSUIFCocA7MA1rlApjDCStmSKdTiA1GirMMz1aLxW1DqrGrRYWoGLZPMxOas2kaQLw5VgRFtxNRkq5wSBMXMLldplBybcjNUYcg4dwkctzW7ikA)