# How to force two types to be incompatible in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, typing

I want to create two types in TypeScript, both of them are a number:

```js
export type GlobalPortIndex = number;
export type TypePortIndex = number;
```

As far as I understand, TypeScript will consider these mutually compatible since they overlap perfectly.

But I want them to be incompatible, so when I type something `GlobalPortIndex`, then if I try to assign a `TypePortIndex` to it, I'd get a type error. This is to make sure I don't mix them up in the code, for example I can't pass one to a function that expects the other.

Any TypeScript tricks to achieve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the term of art here, "[nominal typing](https://betterprogramming.pub/nominal-typescript-eee36e9432d2)", and the common solutions of adding a fake non-runtime property as a "tag" or "brand"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare additional property (or method) to make the 2 classes different:

```
class GlobalPointerIndex extends Number {
  __GlobalPointerIndex: boolean;
}

class TypePortIndex extends Number {
  __TypePortIndex: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on typescript, but wouldn't it be better if you actually wrap the value into class and then static check class type?

Since it looks like you have a object type as `GlobalPortIndex`, and the other one is `TypePortIndex`, they serve a different purpose.

Or perhaps set them as `enum` syntax can resolve this issue?

```js
enum FooKeys {
  FOO = 'foo',
  BAR = 'bar',
}

// probably all you need, but it's a type alias
type FooType = Record<FooKeys, string>;
```

The code above is referenced from this post: [How to build a type from enum values in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55143029/8851585)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
export interface GlobalPortIndex {
brand : 'GlobalPortIndex';
value : number;
}

export interface TypePortIndex {
brand : 'TypePortIndex';
value : number;
}
```

but you have to use it like :

```
const myport = {value:25} as TypePortIndex
```

and access to value like `myport.value`